# The gradient of $ g(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x) $

Tags: analysis, derivatives

> Let $ f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} $ differentiable and $ v:=(v_1,...,v_n)^T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n $ differentiable.
>
> I want to calculate the gradient of $ g(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x) $.

The jacbian matrix of $ f $ is
$$ Df(x)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x)... \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(x)\right)\in \mathbb{R}^{1,n}. $$

For the gradient of $ g(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x) $ I need to calculate the partial derivatives but here I get stuck and I'm not sure if I'm right what I did so far:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (g(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x))\\=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x)+g(x)\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} Df(x)\cdot v(x)+g(x)\cdot  Df(x)\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} v(x) $$

From here I get stuck how to proceed.

Comment: You wrote $Df(x)\in\mathbb R^{1,n}$ is a *matrix*. It is better phrased as a row vector. Then I would say that $Df(x)\cdot v(x)$ is a row vector. Then I get stuck even before taking a derivative: what is $g(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x)\,?$ A row vector? Gradients are usually calculated only for scalars.

Comment: Ah now I see what do you mean. v is supppoesd to be a colum vector. Sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: Corresponding to my correction the expression $ g(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x) $ is in $ \mathbb{R} $. So my correction answers your question now.

Comment: Sorry I see my errors. $Df(x)\cdot v(x)$ is a scalar and so is $g(x)$ and $g(x)\cdot Df(x)\cdot v(x)\,.$ The product rule is correct.